# Unknown Drush version on acquia-cli using ddev 1.21.3

Tags: drush, ddev, acquia

The `ddev pull` command fails when configured to pull from Acquia environments. Only the current version of ddev 1.21.3 is affected. Older versions like 1.21.1 or 1.19.5 are not affected.s

The error message:

```
❯ ddev pull acquia --skip-files
You're about to delete the current database and replace with the results of a fresh pull.
Would you like to continue? [Y/n] (yes): yes
Authenticating...
Saved credentials

In AliasesDownloadCommand.php line 119:

  Unknown Drush version

remote:aliases:download [--destination-dir DESTINATION-DIR] [--all] [--] [<applicationUuid>]

Pull failed: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[This bug](https://github.com/acquia/cli/issues/1190) was reported to Acquia and [fixed](https://github.com/acquia/cli/pull/1209) in version 2.5.3 of Acquia CLI.

The current ddev version 1.21.3 was released with an earlier version 2.5.1 of Acquia CLI which is affected by the bug.  Until a new ddev version can be released — which would bump the version of the upstream dependency — there are two possible workarounds:

1. One-time fix: Manually update to the latest version of Acquia CLI.

   ```
    ddev exec acli self:update
   ```
2. Continual "bleeding edge" updates. ;)

   Update Acquia CLI to latest version when ddev starts.

   Add the following lines to your .ddev/config.yaml file:

   ```
    hooks:
      post-start:
        - exec "acli self:update"
   ```

   Note: This option may expose you to other bugs from latest point releases of Acquia CLI.